# How to get lambda URL from serverless build into static create-react-app

Tags: lambda, create-react-app, apollo, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless framework to build my app.  It consists of the following:

- Apollo Lambda Graphql API
- React Create React App - Deployed to S3/Cloudfront

Both of these get deployed using sls deploy in the one command

My challenge:
I need to build my create react app before I run sls deploy and at this point I don't know what the Endpoint of my graphql API will be.
My create react app obviously will be talking to the graphql api. So given that my react app is static and already built, how do i get it to become aware of this Endpoint URL?

Answer (score 0):

How to create react app and deploy to CloudFront.

https://www.prisma.io/blog/how-to-use-create-react-app-with-graphql-apollo-62e574617cff

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/11/build-simple-web-app-with-express-react-graphql